# How to execute resolvconf without warning?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, resolvconf

I configured NetworkManager, so that it maintains symbolic link from `/etc/resolv.conf` to file in its directory - `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
... /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

Resolvconf gives on attemp to configure DNS:

```
resolvconf -u
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

It contradicts with NetworkManager's settings.
How to get rid of this warning and set up both NetworkManager and resolvconf without conflict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all that is a **WARNING**.
Here is the approach for your question
from the [**resolvconf man page**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html):

```
Normally  the  resolvconf  program is run only by network interface configuration programs
such as ifup(8),  ifdown,  NetworkManager(8),  dhclient(8),  and  pppd(8);  and  by  local
nameservers  such  as  dnsmasq(8).  These programs obtain nameserver information from some
source and push it to resolvconf.
...
To  make  the  resolver  use  this  dynamically  generated resolver configuration file the
administrator   should   ensure   that   /etc/resolv.conf   is   a   symbolic   link    to
/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.   This  link  is  normally  created  on  installation  of the
resolvconf package.  The link is never modified by the resolvconf program itself.  If  you
find  that  /etc/resolv.conf is not being updated, please check to make sure that the link
is intact.
```

So what you need to do in order to get rid of the WARNING is to recreate the symbolik link you have 2 options:

1. Either you recreate the symlink acording to man page with

   ```
   rm -f /etc/resolv.conf # Delete actual file/symlink 
   ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf # recreate the symlink
   ```

   You need to point to the correct file: `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, not to `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`.
2. Tell resolvconf not to show you WARNING using REPORT_ABSENT_SYMLINK
   option:

   ```
   echo 'REPORT_ABSENT_SYMLINK="no"' >> /etc/default/resolvconf
   ```

Comment: You welcome @Bulat M.

Comment: I'm on `ubuntu 16.04`- `/etc/default/resolvconf` does not exist so create it by `nano  /etc/default.resolvconf`