# Cannot ping domainnames, only ip's

Tags: networking, dns, ip, netplan, ping

i'm running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS

I'm able to ping 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 etc. but cannot ping domainnames.
I tried many things but i can't seem to solve this issue. therefore i'm not able to update my system.

few things I discovered:

- I have no `/etc/resolv.conf` file
- I have no `/etc/network/interfaces/` file
- `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` shows `dns=default`
- `systemd-resolve --status` shows 1.1.1.1 as DNS
- My netplan configuration shows

  ```
  network:
    ethernets:
      enp6s0:
        dhcp4: yes
  version: 2
  ```

Can someone help me? Or give me some clues?

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is not used with netplan so don't worry about that. Otherwise You are missing a symlink to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf . See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/872614/how-to-execute-resolvconf-without-warning/873018

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: i've added the version of linux to my post. @StephenBoston tried to make a simlink, did it following the URL you send me, but still the same problem now

Comment: `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf' and `cat /etc/resolv.conf'

Comment: 'ls -l /etc/resolv.conf' gives me:
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
and
'cat /etc/resolv.conf'' gives me:
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory. i think pihole installation and deinstallation messed up my system somehow. really don'' t want to reinstall ubuntu but i think i have no choice.

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf shows that you have resolvconf installed, which is not part of the 18.04 default install.  You may find that removing this package is sufficient to fix the problem.  If not, you can also manually make /etc/resolv.conf a symlink to ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf so that systemd-resolved will be properly used.

Comment: So i tried to remove resolvconf but that package wasn't installed: 'Package 'resolvconf' is not installed, so not removed'. I then made a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf but i sill cannot update or install packages. My system still cannot resolve domainnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue, don't really know how but i wanted to share:
I did a 'dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init' and now it works!

Thanks for your help all!